# Favicon doesn't work in my html script; any other ways to write the script?

Tags: html, css, web, favicon

So, what I am trying to do is to put a favicon on my website's tab, but when I upload the files and everything, I can't see the favicon. Here is the line for the favicon that I know that was suppose to be working: `<link rel = "Shortcut Icon" href = "./Simpsons.ico">`. Can someone give me another way to put up favicon.
P.S 
I already uploaded .ico file, so its not the uploading part fault, its just a script failure.

Comment: Did you check if the path if correct? And add `type="image/x-icon" ` if it works

Comment: It could be path issue as well

Comment: Alright, let me check on that. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You should rename `Shortcut Icon` to `shortcut icon` and give the correct path of ico or png file.

for .ico

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

for .png, you need to specify the type

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

Comment: Okay, I get the most of the part, but I am a bit confused on `href`. Why do you put a link if I have a directory? like instead of `href="./image.ico/.png' `you write `'href="http://example.com/image.png /> ` ? Can you please explain. Thank you !!

Comment: i just gave example you can use href="/yourpath/yourfavicon.ico"